# Данные в бд загружается по лестнице столбцов

Tags: php, sql

У меня в базу данных загружается по лестнице данные, по столбцам, как можно исправить это, вот код:

```
include 'include/db.php'; // Ensure that this file establishes a valid database connection.
include 'assets/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_FILES['add_file']) && $_FILES['add_file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $file_path = $_FILES['add_file']['tmp_name'];
        $selectedOption = $_POST['selected_option'];

        $templateQuery = "SELECT * FROM temp WHERE template_name = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($templateQuery);

        if (!$stmt) {
            echo "Ошибка при подготовке SQL-запроса: " . $db->error;
            exit;
        }

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $selectedOption);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        if (!$result) {
            echo "Ошибка: Не удалось получить данные о шаблоне.";
            exit;
        }

        while ($templateRow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $columnLetters = $templateRow['column_num'];
            $columnNames = $templateRow['mobiles2'];

            $columnLettersArray = explode(',', $columnLetters);
            $columnNamesArray = explode(',', $columnNames);

            $combinedData = array_combine($columnLettersArray, $columnNamesArray);
            $selectedOption = "mobiles2";
            $placeholders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($combinedData), '?'));

            // Prepare the INSERT statement once, outside the row iteration loop
            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $selectedOption (" . implode(',', array_values($combinedData)) . ") VALUES ($placeholders)");

            if (!$stmt) {
                echo "Ошибка при подготовке SQL-запроса: " . $db->error;
                exit;
            }

            $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($file_path);
            $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

            // Iterate through the rows in the file
            for ($i = 2; $i <= $worksheet->getHighestRow(); $i++) {
                $rowData = [];

                foreach ($columnLettersArray as $columnLetter) {
                    $columnIndex = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString(trim($columnLetter));
                    $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($columnIndex, $i);
                    $cellValue = $cell->getValue();
                    $rowData[] = $cellValue;
                }

                // Bind the parameters with the entire row of data
                $bindParams = str_repeat('s', count($rowData));
                $stmt->bind_param($bindParams, ...$rowData);
                
                // Execute the statement for each row
                $stmt->execute();
            }

            $stmt->close();
        }

        echo "Данные были успешно добавлены.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: А что значит данные загружаются по лестнице?

Comment: По столбцам, 1 столбец загрузиться в бд, а остальные нет и выходит так что лестница появляется из данных
1 столбец загрузиться и по строкам выходит так, что только 1 столбец имеет данные.

Comment: Для полной картины не хватает реализации классов из которых вы создаете объекты `$db` и `$stmt` как минимум